# What is the difference between local, non-local, and ISO in unicode date fields?

Tags: javascript, date, unicode, date-fns

I am using the `date-fns` library to format a javascript `date` object to a specific format. `date-fns` uses the [Unicode date field symbols](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table). In this [table](https://date-fns.org/v2.17.0/docs/format) documenting the symbols, there is a distinction between "local" (ie, local day of week: `e`) and symbols that aren't local (day of week: `E`). There are also ISO versions of this (ISO day of week: `i`), as well as stand-alone versions.

I get that when formatting complete dates, I should not be using the stand-alone versions. But I am less clear on the difference between local, non-local, and ISO.

My question: assuming this is the date:

`const date = new Date('2021-04-12')`

Assuming I want to print out `Monday, April 12`, everywhere in the world irrespective of time zone, What is the difference between these:

`format(date, 'EEEE, MMMM d.')` day of week

`format(date, 'iiii, MMMM d.')` ISO day of week

`format(date, 'eeee, MMMM d.')` local day of week

Do they depend on what the local user time is? I saw this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172772/time-zone-issue-involving-date-fns-format) which suggests I need to use `getTimezoneOffset()` to make sure the time is consistent everywhere. But I wasn't sure how the Unicode symbols affect what gets displayed.