# How do I format a date object with no time using date-fns and retaining UTC?

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-formatting, date-fns

This has been making me nuts all day. I understand that JS Date() will set to local time, and thus, make it appear that it's been bumped one day in the past. However, all formatting with date-fns requires a date object, at least as far as I can tell, and it's just plain frustrating to simply format a date, stored ONLY as a date type in Postgres. I'm an inch away from simply parsing and formatting the *correct* UTC date myself and ditching date-fns.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| Date is stored like so in pg: | `2022-11-08` |
| I'm formatting like so, on the front-end: | `format(new Date(job.active_range_start), "MMM dd, yyyy")` |
| The value of `job.active_range_start` is: | `'2022-11-08T00:00:00.000Z'` |
| What I get after formatting w/ date-fns: | `'Nov 07, 2022'` |
| But `new Date(job.active_range_start)` results in this: | `Mon Nov 07 2022 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` |

How can I simply use date-fns `format()` (or whatever) to format the correct UTC date onto the screen? I tried parse(), parseISO(), parseJSON() and all end up giving me the non-UTC localized datetime.

Comment: @Dai Yes, don't have the luxury of removing date-fns from a very large codebase, and don't want devs using two different approaches.

Comment: @Dai I'm really looking for the answer in date-fns at this time. Is it not possible?

Comment: @Dai Feel free to post your answer in Intl - someone will want to know. Thanks.

Comment: Either hack the timezone or use date-fns-tz extension. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52352512/1231844

Comment: @OFRBG I was afraid someone was going to say something like "hack the date-fns lib". To me, it renders date-fns `format()` worthless, as it'd be easier to get format I want without date-fns. Thanks for the link.

Comment: No, not hack the date-fns library. You can either hack the timezone and manually shift it to make it look like you're in UTC OR use the date-fns-tz official extension.

Comment: @OFRBG Right, yeah, I get what you meant. I just tried `format()` in date-fns-tz and the same thing happens, since I have to pass it a `Date()` object, regardless. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dai It's a string, not a Date, like date-fns format() requires.

Comment: @Dai That value is a string and cannot be passed to date-fns format(). I'd have to format manually or just use another lib, which is what I suspected anyhow.

Comment: @Dai Here is the output of what you suggest, which is not the format I need to display: '2022-11-08T00:00:00.000Z'

Comment: @Dai I understand I can take the string apart and do what I want with it...manually. What you suggest is not in "MMM dd, yyyy" format, which was the entire point of this - letting date-fns do that work for me.

Comment: @Dai Did you read the original post?

Comment: ...not close enough, erk. I just realised how much time of yours I wasted barking up the wrong tree. _sorry_